# Как обратиться к элементу body через js

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Доброго времени суток, ХэшКод. Вопрос в следующем: как обратится к элементу body через js. Т.е. мне бы универсальный и просто способ. Для того чтобы определить функцию для события onload.

Answer (score 11):

```
//1
document.body
//2
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
//3
$('body')

//1
document.body.onload = function() {...}
//2
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].onload = function() {...}
//3
$('body').bind("load", function() {...});
//4
$(document).ready(function() {...});
```

Comment: ну и самый банальный, <body onload="onload()">

Comment: те что не jquery не работают в ie 7,8

Comment: но это уже вмешивается в html. как из скрипта сделать и чтобы в ИЕ 7,8 тип топ было?

Comment: [Навешивание событий][1]
[1]:http://javascript.ru/unsorted/top-10-functions#10-addevent

Comment: ну а все таки можно ли это сделать с использование DOM Level 0 Events?

Comment: кто нибудь?

Comment: Разве

    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].onload = function() {...}

не работает во всех версиях IE? 

Попробуйте getElementByID("body"), при этом нужно добавить атрибут id к тэгу:

    <body id="body">

Answer (score 1):

Этого, более чем достаточно.

```
// Подставится то что нам нужно!
var bodyNode = document.body || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

bodyNode.onload = function() {
    // Обработчик событий например:
    alert('Страничка загружена');
};
```

Comment: а в IE7-8 не работает.

Comment: Пишите script в head.

Answer (score -1):

Очень странно что

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')
```

не работает

на крайняк можно тегу body прописать id

```
<body id='body'></body>
document.getElementsById('body')
```

Если

```
document.body.onload = function() {...}
```

то же не работает, можно воспользоваться, опять же, прописыванием события в самом теге

```
<body id='body' onload="onload()"></body>
```

P.S.
Все это костыли. Может быть вам вовсе и не нужно это событие, может вы пытаетесь выполнить код на доме пока еще дом не загружен? На онлоад можно определить какие ни будь переменные, пошаманить над окном браузера но не жеательно обращаться к элементам документа до того как они уже закончат загружаться.

Вот тут привели не мало решений:
[stackoverflow - How to detect if document has loaded (IE 7/Firefox 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978740/javascript-how-to-detect-if-document-has-loaded-ie-7-firefox-3)

Comment: В ответе выше неверное утверждение: Очень странно что `document.getElementsByTagName('body')`
не работает На самом деле всё работает, `getElementsByTagName` возвращает массив, соответственно, надо указать индекс элемента, который хотим получить, в данном случае `[0]`. Правильно так: `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];`